# Does using auto_prepend_file impact performance?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, require, php-ini

Comparing the three alternatives below, how does `auto_prepend_file` impact performance?

1. .htaccess - `php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/file.php`
2. httpd.conf - `php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/file.php`
3. php.ini - `auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/file.php"`
4. included on every php script - `require_once "/path/to/file.php";`

Are all generally equal in performance?

Are there best practices to consider?

Comment: `.htaccess` is evaluated on every request, so it's the slowest option. However, handling how the php code is retrieved, evaluated, executed and cached is dependent on PHP. If you use `mod_php` then this dependency is "transferred" to that module. In reality, you probably won't ever feel the difference. Also, it's one of those optimizations where you might save a microsecond on a million requests. However, if there's a deeper issue with performance your'e experiencing, then it might be worth asking a question about that.

Comment: I recommend using httpd.conf for most configurations dealing with the server. It is read one time once the apache is restarted. For php vars, I would use php.ini.